# Drawing a cone out of 4 equations .

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, dual-cone

how is this a cone?

$$a^2+bc=0$$
$$ab+bd=0$$
$$ac+cd=0$$
$$cb+d^2=0$$

---

I obtained this from $$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}a^2+bc&ab+bd\\ac+cd&cb+d^2\end{bmatrix}=0$$ and I know that the trace and det of $A$ are $0$, and apparently this is a cone said a friend. How is that a cone??

---

$A=\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&-a\end{bmatrix}$ and $A^2 = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a^2-a^2&ab-ba\\ac-ca&-d^2+d^2\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: It is, of course. Why are you interested in this, and what do you think the word `cone' means in mathematics?